# Sinatra session.clear not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am programming a simple login/out web app. Here's the relevent code:

```
get '/logout' do
    session.clear
end

get '/self' do
    if session[:user_id]
        user = User.find session[:user_id]
        user.to_json
    else
        status 401
        {"error" => "Not logged in."}.to_json
    end
end
```

If I call `logout`, and then `self`, it doesn't return `"Not logged in".` Rather the `:user_id` still persists and I am returned the user's details. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
get '/logout' do
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect '/self'
emd
```

Comment: Haven't tried it as I am not on my PC yet, but any reason why session.clear doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure why session.clear doesn't work, from where are you calling '/self'